# i want to upload the file and made custom input file it's working in every browser but not in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to upload the file and made custom input file it's working in every browser but not in safari  the label is hidden  and using label for to click it

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="setting_profile_upload_pspandhe" >
    <input type="file" name="clientphotoouplod" id="uploadtheclientfilephoto86849LJLG" onchange="change_profile()" hidden="hidden" />
    <label for="uploadtheclientfilephoto86849LJLG" id="Aa482018505Aa_" >Upload Profile</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Which version of safari do you have?

Comment: brother version i am using is 5.1.7

Comment: I've tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/s78cptmg/3/) on latest safari version 15, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Safari will hide a label connected with hidden input.
Try to hide your input with css (display: none;)